# Связать установленный apache и php

Tags: apache, php, linux

Всем привет! Друзья, недавно поставил `Linux`, купил пару книг и изучаю систему. Я занимаюсь веб-разработкой, поэтому решил сразу же настроить `MySQL`, `php`, `apache`. Была винда. Решил перейти на более профессиональную ОСь. Проблем с установкой никаких не было. Но, как связать установленный `apache` и `php`? На локалхосте открываются только `html` файлы. Есть какой-нибудь простой способ "связать" `php` и `apache`? Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы используете какую либо вариацию ubuntu linux то посмотрите установлен ли пакет libapache2-mod-php5. Далее надо пойти в каталог /etc/apach2 там будут 2 подкаталога mods-available и mods-enabled. Если модуль php5 установлен то в каталоге mods-available будут 2 файла: php5.conf и php5.load. Надо сделать на них символические ссылки в каталоге mods-enabled и перезапустить apache. После этого вероятно *.php файлы будут правильно обрабатываться.

Comment: Я использую Ubuntu 13.4, по данным папкам лазил в apache2, модуль php5 не установлен. (libapache2-mod-php5 не ставил) Спасибо огромное за помощь! Как я понял, другие модули устанавливаются по той же схеме?

Comment: то что идёт в составе дистрибутива ставится аналогично

Answer (score 0):

Самый, на мой взгляд, простой вариант для начинающего Ubuntоида:

1. Устанвка LAMP:

   ```
   # apt-get install tasksel# tasksel install lamp-server
   ```
2. "Создание" конфига нового сайта:

   ```
   $ cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/default /etc/apache2/sites-available/{имя_сайта}
   ```

   ... и правка конфига:

   ```
   $ vim /etc/apache2/sites-available/{внутреннее_имя_сайта}
   ```
3. Включение сайта:

   ```
   $ a2ensite {внутреннее_имя_сайта}# service apache2 reload
   ```
4. ВЫключение сайта:

   ```
   $ a2dissite {внутреннее_имя_сайта}# service apache2 reload
   ```
5. [Много сайтов на хосте](http://admin.hashcode.ru/questions/4081/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82-%D0%B2-apache2)